# Getting Facebook user location

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Trying to use the Facebook Open Graph to get the location of some users.

Using a url formatted like this:
https://graph.facebook.com/USERID?access_token=XXX

Problem is that I only get this back:

```
{
    "id": "XXX",
    "first_name": "XXX",
    "last_name": "XXX",
    "link": "XXX",
    "name": "XXX",
    "updated_time": "XXX"
}
```

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/, there should also be a location value - but it's not there :(

Any idea how I can get the location too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifically request the `user_location` permission to get that data returned to you.

A user can deny access to this data point, but while you test, you should be allowing the permission and if it doesn't appear, then it means you didn't request access to it, or Facebook is denying access to that data point.

According to Facebook:

> If your app requests this permission Facebook will have to review how your app uses it.

According to the [Facebook Developer Docs here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_location).

Comment: Thanks, but what if we are not building an app? (we are just collecting some data, so we can make statistics about a group of people on Facebook).

Comment: @Louisa: You _need_ an app for any communication with the API. And you are _not allowed_ to request user data for the purpose of doing background analysis like this in the first place.

Comment: I concur.  You need an app.  Otherwise you might only be able to get publicly available data.